# Copy from remote tmux+Vim to local clipboard

Tags: remote, clipboard, tmux

I use Kubuntu and sometimes I ssh out into a server and attach to a tmux session there.

Is there any way I can select -using the mouse or the keyboard- a large chunk of text (more than une screen long, at least) from Vim or the shell and get it into my local system's clipboard?

Answer (score 6):

You can use xclip to get clipboard text to/from your x server to/from the remote system if you used `-X` in your ssh command when you made the connection.  You have to have xclip installed on the system to which you are attaching.  I imagine other clipboard apps can do it, too.  But anyway, configure tmux to call xclip, and you should be good.  For example: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131011/use-system-clipboard-in-vi-copy-mode-in-tmux